# What's wrong with my display?

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, display, xubuntu

I have Xubuntu 16.10 LTS. I have put a new (compatible) 2GB RAM into my old Dell Latitude D610. It's been working for about 2-3 weeks, but then it's acting really strange.

None of the icons appear like they should. They appear like that piece of paper with the X mark on it, and the panel and menu icons are just gone.

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your display or hardware in general, but there are icons missing. Did you uninstall some icon set that you were using?

Comment: Please check your icons folders – `~/.icons/` and `/usr/share/icons/` – for the missing icons. If they are missing, boot a Xubuntu 16.10 Live System and copy them over from `/usr/share/icons` there.

Comment: I did not mess with my icons, and it's fixed now. It appears one of my Linux Kernels were broken, which may have been the cause. Thanks for the tips anyways!!

Comment: Run a memtest! Probably something has destroyed or overwritten some internal database of your desktop layout, but nothing more can be said now, without examining closely your machine. It is also possible, that some daemon or internal process working on your desktop layout crashed as the result of a memory problem. The first task is to check your memory, and act accordingly. The fix of your icons comes after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that one of the Linux Kernels were broken, so that may be the cause.

Thank you all for giving your time and effort to help me in my situation!!